# Setting defaultValue for Preference programmatically

Tags: android

I have an `EditTextPreference` that needs to hold a phone number.  I want to default this preference to the handset's phone number programmatically, so I can't use the XML attribute `android:defaultValue`.  How would I go about doing this?  Here's what I'm trying but the default value still shows as empty:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String number = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        ((EditTextPreference)findPreference("phone_number")).setDefaultValue(number);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using --> onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) ??

Comment: How would I do that?  I just tried it but it's never getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the value in the onPreferenceChange method of the Preference's OnPreferenceChangeListener:

```
    OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value)
        {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference.getKey().equals(PREFS_KEY_PHONE_NUMBER))
            {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue))
                {
                    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    stringValue = tMgr.getLine1Number();
                    ((EditTextPreference)preference).setText(stringValue);
                    preference.setSummary(stringValue);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```